# Python - Hierarchical Risk Parity (PyPortfolioOpt) - rolling windows

Tags: python, pandas, apply, quantitative-finance, rolling-computation

`returns` is a dataframe of 30 stock returns.

I built the below function that computes hierarchical risk parity weights.

```
def hrp_weights(returns):
    w=pd.Series(pypfopt.hierarchical_portfolio.HRPOpt(returns).optimize())
    return w
```

If I run the function `hrp_weights(returns)`I get a pd series of all the 30 weights. It works.

What I would like to do is to run the function in a rolling window, so weights might change every day. Therefore, I coded something like this:

`returns.rolling(252).apply(hrp_weights`)

Unfortunately, I'm aware `rolling` function output does not allow arrays but only scalars. How can I deal with this issue?

Moreover, I get this weird error message: `returns are not a dataframe`

Why does my function work here:`hrp_weights(returns)` and not here `returns.rolling(252).apply(hrp_weights`)?

Thanks for your help

Comment: have you tried looping through your df with a rolling window and capturing the weights this way? btw I would be interested in further discussing HRPOut as I am not finding much online in terms of implementing this

Comment: Hi trock2000, I managed to solve this issue recently. Takes quite long to recap the steps here, but I'm open to discussion and ready to share the code.

Comment: excellent TRGH! I also solved this via iteration and have been running a weekly HRP rebalance model live over the past few weeks. Where is best to move this conversation?

Comment: email better, I'd say